# MacOS Ventura - Google Chrome not appearing in location services

Tags: macos, privacy, ventura

I'm trying to enable Location Services for a site in Google Chrome, and it says that I must enable Location Services for Chrome in the system settings. But in the Location Services settings, Chrome does not a appear in the app list:

[image]

And there is no way to add an app in that list.

I am using MacOS Ventura and I never had this problem in earlier versions.
How can I make Google Chrome to appear in this list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They must have fixed this because Chrome is now appearing in the location services.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).